# Module 'null' not found in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, struts-1

I have created a web application using Struts 1.3. I am using Apache Tomcat to run the application. It's running fine in local. I have deployed the WAR file in Tomcat6 in server machine. When i try to run i am getting the following exception.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Module 'null' not found.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I have checked load-on-startup,struts-config.xml and web.xml. Everything are fine but I do not know why i am getting this exception.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [**ModuleNull**](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ModuleNull)?

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a JSP page directly, and that page has Struts 1 tags in it.

JSP pages with Struts 1 must run through an action. This is okay, since in a reasonably MVC app you should essentially *always* access functionality through the application itself instead of bypassing it and hitting pages directly.